# convert bytearray into pdf javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, pdf

i'm trying to download a pdf report (using jasperReports) directly from browser...
my JS code is above:

```
if (generateReport) {
    Loader.get(`${window.location.origin}/api/${Version.TRIP}/expenses/report-analytics?${getUrlParamsForReport(entity)}`).then(response => {   
         const file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
         const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
         window.open(fileURL, "EPrescription");
    }).catch((error) => {
        SnackbarController.add({
            description: error.message,
            duration: 3000,
        });
        Promise.reject(onError(error));
    });        
}
```

in my java code, the response is:

```
return bos.toByteArray();
```

pdf opens but has no content, no header, nothing!!
help?

Comment: please share the java code of pdf file generation

Comment: sorry for the delay. JasperReport generate a pdf file automatically. 
```
return Response
   .ok()
   .entity(service.generateReportAnalytics(reportAnalytics))
   .header("content-disposition",
      "attachment; filename = ".concat(fileName).concat(".pdf"))
   .build();
```